# plugin.properties and plugin.xml internationalization substitution

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have an eclipse plugin that is suffering from failing to substitute strings in plugin.xml.

I'm building it with tycho, but I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

The resulting jar has plugin.xml and plugin.properties at top level.

For an example, in plugin.xml, I have

```
 <editor
        name="%editor.name"
  ... 
 >
```

and then in plugin.properties:

```
editor.name=Doxia APT Editor
```

But in the "Open With" menu in eclipse indigo, I see %editor.name.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Is it the only missing string?  If all of them are wrong, you may check if you correctly included the "Bundle-Localization: " key on your MANIFEST.MF file.

This key should have the properties file name as its value, without the ".properties" extension.